# Find system sounds in a software

Tags: filesystems, locate

I am using the Wondershare Filmora 9 video editor software on my Windows 10 laptop and I would like to locate and replace the default "Notify me when Video Conversion is Done" sound as I can barely hear it as it is a short 'beep' sound. Is there a way to locate the custom files (this particular sound file in this case) in my System 32 or any other file on the Program Files so I can replace it with a custom sound? I am attaching a screenshot below. Thank you all

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPHqe.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the application sounds are kept in separate files with standard extensions, e.g. .wav, .mp3 or .ogg, changing theme should be easy.

First check if the application uses the Windows default sounds for events, which can be changed easily.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `sounds`, and select *Change system sounds*.
- For each sound that has a loudspeaker icon, e.g. *Default beep*, select the sound and press *Test*.
- If you find one that sounds like that used by *Filmora*, you can change it to a different .wav file using the *Browse* button.
- Test *Filmora* to see if the sound changed.

If the application *does not* use Windows system sounds, then look for the file in the application folder.

- Search in the folder where *Wondershare Filmora 9* resides, perhaps `C:\Program Files\Filmora...` for any sound file extensions. See [Wikipedia for a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_file_format#List_of_formats).
- If you find some, double-click the files to play them.
- When you've identified a problematic file, save it to another folder, then replace it in the original folder with another, louder, sound file of the same name.

However, if the default sounds are *not* kept in separate files then you'd need to get the source code and recompile the application, which is nontrivial.

Comment: You are right, turns out that Wondershare uses the Windows default sound: **'Default Beep'** - the same sound that the System plays when adjusting the volume in the taskbar volume bar. The problem with that is that if I change the **'Default Beep'** with a _notification sound like_ _"Your video is ready"_, every time I adjust the volume in the taskbar I will hear the wrong sound. Is there a workaround to _maybe_ duplicate and edit the **'Default Beep'** _sound file_ so I can assign one sound for the Volume bar, and another, custom sound for the video editor? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can make a louder beep, but you'd need to change Filmora, as outlined above, to use an *individualized* beep.